# How to open a file from an absolute path without having to save a copy

Tags: excel, microsoft-edge, relative-path, absolute-path

So we have our local website to navigate through our drive :
[showcase of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eDCa.png)

Here, each button is a link to something on our drive

One of which is a link to a Excel file :
[showcase of that specific link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjMn3.png)

Now, that Excel file contains relative links to PDFs : [Relative links inside an Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIES8.png)

If we click on that button linked to that Excel file from Edge (2nd screen), a prompt appears asking if we want to "Open" the file or "Save as", but the issue is... if we choose "Save as", obviously the links inside that Excel file wont work (unless we save it at the same location), so that's totally normal, the correct option would be to "Open" it.

The problem is that opening a file from Edge... actually doesn't open a file at all, it saves it locally under the AppData path of our machine and THEN opens it.

That means even in that case, the paths inside our Excel file wont work either because they are relative.

I know one solution would be to change all links to absolute links inside that Excel file, but that is a tedious work (because there are a LOT of links, we would have to create a script or something to do that).

So my question is, is there any way to directly open that Excel file from the path specified in the button's link, instead of saving it first locally under "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temp\MicrosoftEdgeDownloads\f02875af-f436-47bb-b7e5-f3caa96df03f" ?

This is not an issue when using Internet Explorer.

Thank you in advance for any help.
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow intranet zone file URL links from Microsoft Edge to open in Windows File Explorer, you can try this Edge policy: [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled).

Otherwise I don't recommend you to do this, based on the security issues already mentioned.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer, that seems to be the fix I was looking for.
However, I can't seem to find how to enable that policy, could you please help me implement this ?

Thank you again
Have a good week-end
Kind regards,

Comment: Type `Edit Group Policy` and open the policy editor, then you can find it according to the path:`Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/Content settings`. As [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDd8V.png) shows, just enable the policy.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late late answer ! So my Microsoft Edge is listed under Administrative Template/Windows Components/Microsoft Edge. Inside it, I don't have that GPO listed :/

Comment: Well, I guess that should be the group policy path for Legacy Edge. Under the new Microsoft Edge, you need to install its new Administrative Templates. And the policy works after Edge 95, you need to make sure its version meets the requirements. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#1-download-and-install-the-microsoft-edge-administrative-template) to install it properly.